# Get string value of array on remote server

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xml-rpc

I'm trying to find the content of an array on a remote server.  All I can send back currently is strings (due to limitations in the PHP implementation of xmlrpc).   Normally, I'd just use `var_dump()`, but that returns void.  I've tried using `var_export`, but I get XML errors, even when I cast the result to a string.

How can I get the string representation of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize):

```
$string = serialize( $array);
```

Then use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) to get it back into an array:

```
$array = unserialize( $string);
```

You can also use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) / [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) if you're interested in a JSON formatted string.

```
$string = json_encode( $array);
$array = json_decode( $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP serialize, json_encode .... These are alternate methods to encode an object.